# Bounded Right Inverse

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

If a linear operator between two Banach spaces is surjective and bounded, can we get any information about a right inverse? For example, is it bounded?

Thanks, trying to understand trace operator stuff on the Sobolev spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T: X \to Y$ is bounded and surjective, the Open Mapping Theorem says  there is an isomorphism $S:\; X/\ker(T) \to Y$ such that
$T = S \circ \pi$, where $\pi: X \to X/\ker(T)$ is the quotient map.  The
trouble is, a quotient of $X$ might not be isomorphic to a closed subspace of $X$, so there might not be a bounded right inverse.  For example, every separable Banach space is isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell^1$, but not every Banach space is isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell^1$ (e.g. $\ell^2$ is not).

Comment: what if in this particular context, we know that a right inverse exists? I am currently trying to understand any right inverse of the Trace Operator $T:H^1(\Omega) \to H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega).$

Comment: A right inverse exists: any surjective linear operator has a right inverse (which can be defined e.g. using a Hamel basis), but not necessarily a bounded one.

Comment: If I get it correctly, the open mapping theorem also yields the existence of a bounded right inverse (which may not be linear). Or do I muss something?

Comment: I don't see how the open mapping theorem yields that.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T : X \to Y$ be a surjection between Banach spaces $X$, $Y$.

- You can get a linear right inverse, cf. Robert Isreal's comment.
- You can get a bounded right inverse: The open mapping theorem yields $r > 0$ with $B_r^Y \supset T \, B_1^X$. Hence, for $y \in Y$ you find $x \in X$ with $T \, x = y$ and $\|x\| \le \|y\|/r$.
- You cannot always get the existence of a linear *and* bounded right inverse. In [Existence of right inverse.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887843/existence-of-right-inverse) it is mentioned that this is true iff the kernel of $T$ is complemented in $X$.