# is there a linear continuous selection in a normed quotient space?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given $(E,\parallel \; \parallel)$ a Banach space ( complete normed space), and $F\subset E$  a closed linear subspace. There's a natural norm on the quotient linear space $E/F$, and a natural quotient map ( linear and continuous ) :

$P:E\longrightarrow E/F$ with
$P(x)=[x]=\{y\in E \; : \; (x-y)\in F \} $ for $x\in E$.

I want to know if it is possible to find a linear continuous map $R:E/F \longrightarrow E$ such that $P\circ R=Id_{E/F}$?
Or under what kind of conditions someone could has a positive answer?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887843/existence-of-right-inverse) may help. And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301255/surjective-bounded-operator-in-banach-spaces-without-bounded-right-inverse).

Comment: Thank you David Mitra.